# How to install php7 on solaris 10 with OpenSSL 1.0.1

Tags: software-installation, solaris, php, gcc, openssl

I am trying to install php7 on Solaris 10.

OpenSSL 1.0.1 was installed from https://www.opencsw.org/packages/libssl1_0_0/

To check for the installed ssl I did

```
pkginfo -i | grep -i "ssl"
```

and I got this output:

```
application CSWlibssl1-0-0                   libssl1_0_0 - Openssl 1.0 runtime libraries
GNOME2      SUNWopenjade                     DSSSL-Engine for SGML documents
GNOME2      SUNWopenjade-devel               DSSSL-Engine for SGML documents  - developer files
GNOME2      SUNWopenjade-root                DSSSL-Engine for SGML documents - platform independent files, / filesystem
GNOME2      SUNWopenjade-share               DSSSL-Engine for SGML documents - platform independent files, /usr/share
system      SUNWopenssl-commands             OpenSSL Commands (Usr)
system      SUNWopenssl-include              OpenSSL Header Files
system      SUNWopenssl-libraries            OpenSSL Libraries (Usr)
system      SUNWopenssl-man                  OpenSSL Manual Pages
system      SUNWopensslr                     OpenSSL (Root)
utility     openssl                          openssl 1.0.1j SPARC 64bit Solaris 10
```

Then, to check install path, I did

```
pkgchk -l CSWlibssl1-0-0 | egrep '^(Pathname|Type)'
```

which gave

```
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0
Type: directory
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0/engines
Type: directory
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0/engines/lib4758cca.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libaep.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libatalla.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libcapi.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libchil.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libcswift.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libgmp.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libgost.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libnuron.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libpadlock.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libpk11.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libsureware.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libubsec.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/libssl.so.1.0.0
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0
Type: directory
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0/engines
Type: directory
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0/engines/lib4758cca.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libaep.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libatalla.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libcapi.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libchil.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libcswift.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libgmp.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libgost.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libnuron.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libpadlock.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libpk11.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libsureware.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/lib/sparcv9/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libubsec.so
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/share/doc/libssl1_0_0
Type: directory
Pathname: /opt/csw/share/doc/libssl1_0_0/CHANGES
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/share/doc/libssl1_0_0/CHANGES.SSLeay
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/share/doc/libssl1_0_0/FAQ
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/share/doc/libssl1_0_0/INSTALL
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/share/doc/libssl1_0_0/NEWS
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/share/doc/libssl1_0_0/PROBLEMS
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/share/doc/libssl1_0_0/README
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/share/doc/libssl1_0_0/README.ASN1
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/share/doc/libssl1_0_0/README.CSW
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/share/doc/libssl1_0_0/README.ENGINE
Type: regular file
Pathname: /opt/csw/share/doc/libssl1_0_0/license
Type: regular file
```

Then I did this:

```
#CC="/opt/gcc-4.9.0/bin/gcc" \
 #export CC
 #CFLAGS="-std=gnu99 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" \
 # export CFLAGS
 # LDFLAGS="-L/opt/gcc-4.9.0/lib -L/usr/local/lib -R/opt/gcc-4.9.0/lib"
 # export LDFLAGS
 # cd /php-7.2.4
```

so, my configure script in the php directory looks like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php/lib --with-apxs2=/usr/apache2.4.3/bin/apxs --with-ldap=/opt/gcc-4.9.0/lib \
 --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --with-pdo-mysql  --with-zlib --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local \
 --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local --with-pcre-dir=/usr/local --with-gettext=/usr/local --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local --with-curl --with-openssl \
 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/csw/lib/ --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local --with-gnu-ld --enable-shared --enable-mbstring \
 --with-oci8=instantclient,/ebsproddb/oracle/11.2.0/instantclient \
 --enable-exif --enable-sockets --enable-soap --enable-zip  --enable-ftp --enable-mysqlnd --disable-zend-signals --disable-static
```

However the configure fails after several attempt with.

```
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure: error: OpenSSL version 1.0.1 or greater required.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're not specify openssl header files.

```
--with-openssl=DIR      Include OpenSSL support (requires OpenSSL >= 1.0.1)
```

So, might be as follows

```
./configure --with-openssl=/path_to_header_files --with-openssl-dir=/opt/csw/lib....etc
```

Please check the output of configure script with `--help` option.

Comment: didn't quite get that ?

Comment: By the way, openssl 1.0.1 has vulnerability. I think you should not use that version.https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-217/product_id-383/version_id-125308/Openssl-Openssl-1.0.1.html

Comment: yes, it was only --with-openssl. so, add path to header files and please try again. i hope it works. thanks.

Comment: tried editing the header , but it kept giving : configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>

Comment: so, I found out that include directory in the csw , meant to contain the headers was empty, so I did `/opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -y -i libssl_dev` to install libssl_dev , then `--with-openssl=/opt/csw --with-openssl-dir=/opt/csw/  `

Comment: @GAD3R , please can you help have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/453418/293072