# How to install php7 on solaris 10 with Oracle Instant client

Tags: compiling, solaris, php, oracle-database

I am  trying to install php7 with oracle on Solaris 10.

The oracle instant-client-basic and instant-client sdk was downloaded from oracle

The instant client-basic was unzipped and this creates the directory instantclient_11_2

The instan tclient-sdk was unzipped and this was found in instantclient_11_2 directory

Two Symbolic Links were created .

```
 ln -s /instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so.11.1 /instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so


ln -s /instantclient_11_2/libocci.so.11.1 /instantclient_11_2/libocci.so
```

my config script looks like this

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php/lib --with-apxs2=/usr/apache2.4.3/bin/apxs --with-ldap=/opt/gcc-4.9.0/lib \
 --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --with-pdo-mysql --with-zlib --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local --with-pcre-dir=/usr/local \
--with-gettext=/usr/local --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local --with-openssl=/opt/csw/ --with-openssl-dir=/opt/csw/ --with-gd --with-ldap=/opt/csw/ --enable-shared \ 
--with-oci8=instantclient,/instantclient_11_2 --enable-mbstring  --enable-exif  --enable-soap --enable-ftp --enable-mysqlnd --disable-zend-signals \
--disable-static --enable-opcache=no
```

The configure script will complete without issue , however when I run

```
gmake
```

It will run shortly and end with

```
 ld: fatal: file /instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

I thought it was because I am using 64 bit version of the instant client , I then downloaded the 32 bit instant client, extracted and linked the same way.

It also configured successfully but when a gmake is run it ended with

```
/libclntsh.so: wrong ELF machine type: EM_386
```

What am I doing wrong?